# How to enforce painting in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QMainWindow` instance, which consecuctively needs to read to xml files. The first file holds all necessary information to construct the ui and the second all meta-data. So in my `MainWindow`'s `open` function i would like to paint the ui after reading the first file like:

*in `MainWindow`'s `open` scope:*

```
readFirstFile(QString filename);
update();
readSecondFile(QString filename);
```

But the above has no effect. How can i enforce painting before reading the second file?

Comment: I presume you do this since file reading is "slow" and you want the UI to respond responsively. Instead, farm out file reading to the thread pool, and have the worker functor thread-safely update your UI's state. The painting will be done automatically without you having to worry about it, as the event loop will keep on spinning to process the data from the workers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need an immediate repaint you can use `repaint()`  instead of `update()`.

from the Qt doc of `QWidget::update()`

> This function does not cause an immediate repaint; instead it schedules a paint event for processing when Qt returns to the main event loop. This permits Qt to optimize for more speed and less flicker than a call to repaint() does.

Comment: That seems correct but results in this behaviour: as soon as `repaint()` is invoked, the objects created in `MainWindow` dissapear (i.e.: some buttons and a backround image) but the objects created while reading the first file will show when reading the second file is finished

Comment: I guess your file reading methods are blocking and take some time then? If so you should maybe run them in a background thread or something or I don't know why the rest of your UI is "disappearing".

Comment: I need to figure out what blocks the repaint. For now this question is clearly answered. Thanks

Comment: @tobilocker You block the repaint. The file reading is done in the main thread: while it happens, the UI is unresponsive. Don't do that and your problem will automatically be fixed.